# recursion- return the value twice | python

Tags: python, recursion

we were given an assignment to write a method that gets a list, and return true if all the elements are positive, false otherwise.
We were told to implement recursion in our solution, so I wrote the following thing:

```
def positive_list(li):
    if len(li) == 1 and li[0] > 0:
        return True
    else:
        if li[0] < 0:
            return False
        return positive_list(li[1::])
```

So the method works just fine, but for `print positive_list([1, 2, 3, 4])` in would print:

```
True
True
```

Why does it do it? and how do I get rid of the extra Boolean?

*Edit- found my problem, somehow it did not work on my laptop while working in my main rig

Comment: This code is not *printing* anything. Where are you using `print`?

Comment: You are probably printing out something which I am sure is *completely* unrelated to the code snippet that you've shared. Btw, `print positive_list([1, 2, 3, 4])` prints `True` just once.

Comment: I added a *print positive_list([1,2,3,4])* at the end and there is a single 'True' on my display when I run the program

Comment: yes... your code is absolutely fine... you might be printing true somewhere... please recheck...

Comment: BTW, your code isn't consistent with the way it handles zero in the list. Consider what happens when `li[0] == 0`.

Comment: Check with `print 'positive_list:', postivie_list([1, 2, 3, 4]), 'done'` And see if there are two identical output.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no `print` statement in the code you have shared, it is never gonna print any value.

Your code seems to be alright for the non-empty list, but it will fail if your input list is empty. It will fail with message `IndexError: list index out of range`.

To prevent this, you could modify your `if len(li) == 1 and li[0] > 0:` statement as:

```
if len(li) == 0 or (len(li) == 1 and li[0]) > 0):
```

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure why you need recursion but here is a possible answer.

```
def positive_list(given_list):
    for elm in given_list:
        if elm < 0:
            return False
    return True if given_list else False


print positive_list([1, 2, 3, 4])
print positive_list([1, -2, 3, 4])
print positive_list([1, 0, 3, 4])
print positive_list([])
```

and here are the results:

```
True
False
True
False
```

Comment: OP needs recursion **because it was part of the problem specification.**  Consequently, this is not an answer to the question.